# I want to put values in a webform using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the below VBA code to automate log in to a third party application. When i ran the below code it only opens Internet explorer browser and navigate to the link then do nothing.
here is my code:

```
Sub Login_Aravo()

Dim ie

Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear

sURL = "https://demo.aravo.com/"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate sURL

Do

' Wait till the Browser is loaded

Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

ie.Document.all.Item("j_username").Value = "Nothing" 'Enter your username here

ie.Document.all.Item("j_password").Value = "Nothing" 'Enter your password here

ie.Document.all.Item("login").Click


' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed

Err_Clear:

If Err <> 0 Then

'Debug.Assert Err = 0

Err.Clear

Resume Next

End If

End Sub
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Arup

Comment: I tried as you told but when the login page came,my code does not feed anything to the Username and Password field. The page remains there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if you step through it slowly.

The issue is that you are loading a page that redirects, so it is falsely triggering the READYSTATE complete after the first page is loaded.

The easiest way to correct for this is to just load the page you ultimately end up loading. If you change your sURL to this:  `sURL = "https://demo.aravo.com/aems/login.do"` the code works perfectly.

Alternately, you could make a secondary loop after your first loop that waits to be sure your login-page has loaded. Something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
 'This will loop until the correct page loads.
 Do
     Err.Clear
     ie.document.all.Item("j_username").Value = ""
 Loop Until Err.Number = 0
```

Comment: Daniel it is not working, same issues i am having... Please help me here